# Java logically concatenate arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have several 2D-arrays which appear in different combinations, i.e. one of them defines the center and eight others are logically (not physically) placed to the left, right, top, top-right, etc. The 'new array' is accessed like this:
if the x and y indices are within the boundaries of the center array, the center array is accessed. If the indices exceed the boundaries (either < 0 or larger than the with,height) the appropriate neighbor array is accessed (e.g. for x < 0 and y < 0 the top-left array is accessed).

At ther moment I am solving this re-mapping of array indices manually. Here is one example (there is no need to understand the context; I just wanted to show the structure of the described process):

```
public float noiseValueForCorner(int x, int y, int colorRight, int colorLeft, int colorTop,
int colorBottom, int tileLeftUp, int tileRightUp, int tileLeftLower, int tileRightLower)
{
// Out of bounds
    if (x < -K2 || y < -K2 || x >= 4*K || y >= 4*K)
        return -1.0f;

if (y >= 0 && y < K2)
{
    // corner itself
    if (x >= 0 && x < K2)
    return CornerNoise.noise[x][y];
    // left color
    else if (x < 0 && colorLeft >= 0)
    return ColorNoise[colorLeft].noise[K2-y-1][N2K+x];
    // right color
    else if (x >= K2 && colorRight >= 0)
    return ColorNoise[colorRight].noise[K2-y-1][x-K2];
}
else if (y < 0)
{
    // top color
    if (x >= 0 && x < K2 && colorTop >= 0)
    return ColorNoise[colorTop].noise[x][N2K+y];
        // top left tile
    else if (x < 0 && tileLeftUp >= 0)
    return TileNoise[tileLeftUp].noise[N2K+x][N2K+y];
    // top right tile
    else if (x >= K2 && tileRightUp >= 0)
    return TileNoise[tileRightUp].noise[x-K2][N2K+y];
}
else //if (y >= K2)
{
    // bottom color
    if (x >= 0 && x < K2 && colorBottom >= 0)
    return ColorNoise[colorBottom].noise[x][y-K2];
    // bottom left tile
    else if (x < 0 && tileLeftLower >= 0)
    return TileNoise[tileLeftLower].noise[N2K+x][y-K2];
    // bottom right tile
    else if (x >= K2 && tileRightLower >= 0)
    return TileNoise[tileRightLower].noise[x-K2][y-K2];
}

return 2.0f;
}
```

The problem is that due to many calls of this method my whole program is quite slow. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. I thought of some way to efficiently translate the indices to the memory adresses of the single arrays, to get a new array (since array accesses are done quite fast).

Comment: If this particular section is slow, would offloading it to a Thread help?

Comment: How often do the array or their placement change and how often do you access a "placement configuration"?

Comment: Aside from the apperent tediousness of manual handcoding all cases, the code shown is not necessarily slow. Use a profiler to find usage frequencies, bottlenecks. FindBugs might also shed some light.

Comment: Agreed with Joop, this part of the code isn't particulary slow in itself: a few comparaison, arrays acces. Find why it's slow. Memoisation could help. If you're using big arrays with lot of computation, you should look for parrallel computing, like multi-threading. I don't remember if Java has GPU frameworks. Why do you return TileNoise[...] and sometimes ColorNoise[...] ?

Comment: @Joop: I identified this part of my code to be an issue, since simply returning an array element (for testing purposes) resulted in a six times faster computation. So yeah the usage frequency is quite high.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the coordinates by some simple (and therefore quick) arithmetic operations. No ifs required for anything other that bounds-checking.

To begin with the simple case, 9 arrays, squares of the same dimension:

Make an [a x a] array of your arrays. You can select the array by the coordinates by **a**, you obtain the indices within the array by taking the modulus of the coordinates with respect to a.

As an example: if you have 9 arrays (that's a 3x3 array of arrays), each 5x5, your raw indices will run from (-5, -5) to (5,5). It is probably simplest to normalise by adding in this case 5, in general add the lowest index value. So the example indexes now run from (0, 0) to (10,10)

To find the array divide by 5. The result is the indices of the array to use, in the range (0,0) to (2,2). You can now access the appropriate array. Call that result normalised x and y: nx, ny.

```
  theArrays[nx, ny]
```

The index within the array is just obtained by using the % operator with the array dimension.

Example: (8, -4) normalise to (13, 1) access

```
  (theArrays[2, 0])[3, 1];
```

Extending this to cases where the central array is large and the outer arrays are small is managed when we normalise by adding the dimension of the central array. In effect the lower/left arrays are translated leaving a gap.

As an example, central array is 5 x 5, corner external arrays are 3 x 3, and central external arrays are 5 x 3 or 3 x 5. The bottom left corner array would run from [-3,-3] to [0, 0] The normalisation moves the bottom left corner array to start at [2, 2].

In the case where the external arrays are larger than the central array the arithmetic gets slightly more complex, but still can be done with no if statement.

As an example, the central array is 3 x 3, and the outer arrays are 5 x 5, 3 x5 and 5 x 3. Considering just one dimension:

```
    array 0         1        2
 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 | 0 1 2 | 3 4 5 6 7
```

So the input ranges from -5 ... 7.

we want to map to arrays 0, 1 or 2

-5 to -1 => 0, 0 to 2 => 1, 3 to 7 => 2

One way to do that is simply use a lookup table. Which is probably the fastest. For the record here's some arithmetic to do it. Array sizes e and c (edge and center), requested index i

```
 index of array = (2 * ((i + e) / (e + c) ) ) + ( ((i + e ) % (e + c) ) / e)

 sample values: 
       -5 =>  0 +  0 => 0
       -3 =>  0 +  0 => 0
       -1 =>  0 +  0 => 0
        0 =>  0 +  1 => 1
        2 =>  0 +  1 => 1
        3 =>  2 +  0 => 2
```

For the index within the array it's even easier

```
 index within array = (( i + e ) % (e + c) ) % e

       -5 =>  0 % 5 => 0
       -3 =>  2 % 5 => 2
       -1 =>  4 % 5 => 4
        0 =>  5 % 5 => 0
        2 =>  7 % 5 => 2
        3 =>  0 % 5 => 0
```

Comment: This is generally a great idea, however my arrays do not have the same size. More precisely the center has  _a_ x _a_ elemens, the left and right arrays have _b_ x _a_ elements, the top and bottom arrays _a_ x _b_ elements and the four others (top-left, top-right,...) have a size of _b_ x _b_. Thus, I cannot simply divide the indices by the width or height of one array.

Comment: is b < a ? If so you can pad your b arrays so as to produce the same effect.

Comment: and if b > a it is also possible to come up with a nice arithmetic approach. I'll extend my answer with that tomorrow. Summary: first divide by (a+b), then divide the result by b.